# Dropdown menu moves other content

Tags: css

What should I change in this code http://jsfiddle.net/sohuzpLy/ to make dropdown menu will not move other content?
Tried some things with `position:absolute` and `position:relative`, but still couldn't get it working.

Can anyone check it, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nav` element as a wrapper for the navigation; I suppose this was your idea originally. Making the ordered list `absolute` positioned and then making the wrapper `relative` positioned should fix that. However, you will need to play around with the padding to get it properly set.

In order to avoid this padding issue, I would suggest that you separate the content with its own wrapper. This way you can make it go underneath the navigation wrapper, and that's how most solutions work anyway.

```
.content {
    padding-top: 2.5em;
}

nav {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a code snippet to represent the suggested solution:

```css
.content {
    padding-top: 2.5em;
}

nav {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

ol > li {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

ol li ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ol li ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}

ol li:hover {
    background-color: #333333;
}

ol li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ol li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #444444;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ol>
        <li>Section 1
            <ul>
                <li>1.1</li>
                <li>1.2</li>
                <li>1.3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Section 2
            <ul>
                <li>2.1</li>
                <li>2.2</li>
                <li>2.3</li>
                <li>2.4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Section 3
            <ul>
                <li>3.1</li>
                <li>3.2</li>
                <li>3.3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
</nav>


<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu suscipit nibh. Sed imperdiet velit nec velit varius, id maximus sem semper. Pellentesque malesuada augue at ex dapibus, quis tristique erat ornare. Mauris viverra vulputate urna imperdiet tristique. Nunc et interdum turpis. Phasellus vitae odio quam. Donec imperdiet in nibh eu viverra. Ut vestibulum efficitur odio, id malesuada ligula facilisis eu. Pellentesque consequat mauris lectus, et malesuada metus dignissim eget. Curabitur ut quam felis. Ut luctus blandit est, et elementum urna rutrum ac. Quisque posuere lorem ac blandit accumsan.</p>
    <p>Cras convallis est lectus, ac venenatis dolor interdum a. Sed sit amet mattis urna. Nulla id efficitur sem, viverra dapibus magna. Donec a massa vitae odio lobortis commodo. Donec non enim aliquam, lobortis ex vel, euismod tellus. Etiam lacinia, dolor ac laoreet pulvinar, augue odio bibendum justo, sed tincidunt nisl ipsum eget urna. Etiam ligula urna, mollis sed facilisis nec, ultrices et mi. Quisque pretium vestibulum risus at elementum. Pellentesque nisl risus, aliquam in erat sit amet, mattis fringilla est. Ut malesuada ullamcorper ultricies. Etiam vitae consequat elit, in pharetra turpis. Curabitur maximus eros quis varius facilisis.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the minumum height to higher values for it. It helped mine, but I did it based on the method found here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp